# [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "icon" at <FontAwesomeIcon> at <RouterLink key="products" to= {name: 'products'} class="box flex flex-col

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite

*I am using Vue 3 and vite.*

for icons i use font awesome.

this is my code:

```
</template>
  <div class="pages flex flex-col bg-maincolor rounded-lg py-3">
      <router-link
        v-for="page in pagesList"
        :key="page.title"
        :to="{ name: page.to }"
        class="box flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-[70px]"
      >
        <font-awesome-icon
          :icon="[page.itype, page.iname]"
          class="text-headcolor text-xl mb-2"
        />
        <font-awesome-icon />
        <span class="text-headcolor text-sm uppercase">{{ page.title }}</span>
      </router-link>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "AppNavbar",
  setup: () => {
    const pagesList = ref([
      { title: "about", to: "about", itype: "far", iname: "user" },
      { title: "resume", to: "resume", itype: "far", iname: "rectangle-list" },
      { title: "works", to: "works", itype: "fas", iname: "eye" },
      { title: "blog", to: "blog", itype: "fas", iname: "newspaper" },
      { title: "contact", to: "contact", itype: "far", iname: "paper-plane" },
      { title: "products", to: "products", itype: "fas", iname: "laptop-code" },
    ]);
    return {
      pagesList,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

### everything was working till I make that loop

my question is how can i solve it where is the problem? i needed it to be more dynamic but i doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because there is a second interpreted `FontAwesomeIcon` component created with no `icon` prop being passed:

```
<font-awesome-icon
      :icon="[page.itype, page.iname]"
      class="text-headcolor text-xl mb-2"
    />
<font-awesome-icon /> <---- right here
```

It looks you had it as a closing tag before, or your IDE made it automatically while you were rewriting your code. However if it was intended to have two FontAwesomeIcons, then obviously you'd pass data for the `icon` prop as well.

You can resolve this issue by removing `/>`, or removing `<font-awesome-icon />`.